# Selecting a specific metafield for a product using Shopify API, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, shopify

In liquid templates this is achieved like so:

```
{{ product.metafields.book.author }}
```

Which returns the value of 'author' for it's key 'book'

I'm using Shopify API and Ruby on Rails and have successfully looped over each metafield for a given product:

**In the controller:**

```
@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 10})
```

**In the view:**

```
<% @products.metafields.each do |metafield| %>
<%= metafield.key %> : <%= metafield.value %>
<% end %>
```

This returns all of the metafields for a product, as expected. How do I return only those metafields matching a specific key i.e. 'book' from the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
ShopifyAPI::Metafield.find(:first,:params=>{:resource => "products", :resource_id => 94549954, :key => "book"})
```

Answer (score 10):

```
# add metafield
product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(product_id)
product.add_metafield(ShopifyAPI::Metafield.new({
   :description => 'Author of book',
   :namespace => 'book',
   :key => 'author',
   :value => 'Kurt Vonnegut',
   :value_type => 'string'
}))

# retrieve metafield
author = ShopifyAPI::Metafield.find(:first,:params=>{:resource => "products", :resource_id => product.id, :namespace => "book", :key => "author"}).value
```

More info: http://www.shopify.com/technology/3032322-new-feature-metafields

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick:

```
<% product.metafields.each do |metafield| %>
    <% if metafield.key == "book" %>
        <%= metafield.key %>: <%= metafield.value %><br/>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% product.metafields.each do |metafield| %>
    <% if metafield.key.include?("book") %>
        <%= metafield.key %>: <%= metafield.value %><br/>
    <% else %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I imagine this is better off in the controller, rather than the view. Any adice would be cool

Comment: You wouldn't use that code in the controller, as you are printing out the metafields, which is what you naturally do in the view

Answer (score 0):

```
ShopifyAPI::Metafield.find(:all,:params=>{:product_id => product.id, :key=> 'book'})
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. I'm having some trouble implementing this, would you mind elaborating on the code a little please?

Comment: This for me just returns an empty array. I've tried in IRB using minimal params i.e. ShopifyAPI::Metafield.find(:all,:params=>{:product_id => 94549896})

Comment: This works: ShopifyAPI::Metafield.find(:first,:params=>{:resource => "products", :resource_id => 94549954, :key => "book"})

Answer (score 0):

You can get all metafields for a product

```
@product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(params[:id])
```

After that, you can get its metafields

```
@metafields = @product.metafields
```

Or if you need just a specific metafield for that product

```
@metafield = ShopifyAPI::Product::Metafield.find(:all, where: {"product_id = ? AND metafield.key = ?", product.id, "book"})
```